# Simple javascript to update a textbox when a button is hit?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple form that I'm playing around with and I'm trying to update a textbox value when a command button is clicked. The command button is called btnVerifyLocation and the textbox is called txtGeoLocation. I've attempted to do this in Javascript with the following:

The code I have is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="testing">

$("btnVerifyLocation").click(function ()
{
     $("input[name*='txtGeoLocation']").val("testing");
});

</script>
```

However when I click the button nothing happens.

Comment: can you add your html?

Comment: `$("btnVerifyLocation")` is looking for an element `<btnVerifyLocation>`. Assume you used an ID? Try `#btnVerifyLocation`

Comment: Not sure you need the *. Try to remove the star. Also make sure you wrap that to be called when the DOM is ready. Also, you need to specify the selector with a . or #.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) You're missing a # in 'btnVerifyLocation' (I'm assuming that's its ID, otherwise if it's a class then use '.btnVerifyLocation'

B) Second, this should be in a `$(document).ready()`, otherwise you are trying to bind a click handler to a DOM element that hasn't yet been rendered.

Code should be as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnVerifyLocation').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // In case this is in a form, don't submit the form
        // The * says "look for an input with a name LIKE txtGeoLocation, 
        // not sure if you want that or not
        $('input[name*="txtGeoLocation"]').val('testing'); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Note that you can also use `$(function() {...})` instead of `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery’s selector function uses CSS selector syntax, so to identify an object with an ID, you need to prefix the ID with a `#`:

```
$("#btnVerifyLocation").click(function () {
    $("input[name*='txtGeoLocation']").val("testing");
});
```

Also just in case: You do have jQuery included, right?

Comment: haha, jQuery included; I glazed over that one. Good catch to ask that.

Comment: Thankfully it is, I had not prefixed my id with a '#'